# Building chessboard with javascript in the console

Tags: javascript

Im doing this problem from eloquent javascript, it should print like this

```
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
```

but cant seem to work out how to alternate the rows. So far I just came up with the grid.

```
# # # # 
# # # # 
# # # # 
# # # # 
# # # # 
# # # # 
# # # # 
# # # #
```

using this code

```
var hash = ''
var size = 8


for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        hash.charAt(hash.length-1) === '#' ? hash += ' ': hash += '#'
    }
    hash += '\n'
} 
console.log(hash)
```

the code they used to answer the problem is this

```
var size = 8;

var board = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
      board += " ";
    else
      board += "#";
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

but I'm sure there's a way using my code instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously there is no way to make it work without changing your code, because your code doesn't work, and the way to make it work is by using the code that works.

Comment: `if(i+1) % 2 !== 0 //even row, prepend a space to the string`

Answer (score 1):

You should make the difference between odd/even rows. This you can do by looking at the sum of the row and column indexes: if exactly one of them is odd, produce a hash, else a space:

```js
var hash = ''
var size = 8

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        (i + j) % 2 ? hash += '#': hash += ' '
    }
    hash += '\n'
} 
console.log(hash)
```

Note that you can move the assignment out of the ternary operator:

```
        hash += (i + j) % 2 ? '#' : ' '
```

But honestly, it is not advised to keep adding to a string, since in JavaScript strings are immutable, so you really create a new string with each `+=` operation.

This is how I would suggest doing it with this ES6 code:

```js
var hash = ''
var size = 8

hash = Array.from(Array(size), (_, i) =>
  Array.from(Array(size), (_, j) =>
     (i+j)%2 ? '#' : ' '
  ).join('')
).join('\n');

console.log(hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the Even rows and insert a additional space at the start of the string.

`// Identify the even row and add an Extra space
if( i % 2 === 0) { hash+= ' '}`

Following code should produce the expected output.

```js
var hash = ''
var size = 8
                 
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            
    // Identify the even row and add an Extra space
    if( i % 2 === 0) { hash+= ' '}

    for (var j = 0; j < size-1; j++) {
        hash.charAt(hash.length-1) === '#' ? (hash += ' '):  (hash += '#')
     }
     hash += '\n'
  } 
console.log(hash)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set the bound of the `j` loop one lower given `i%2 == 0`? Otherwise you will print an additional character.

Comment: i only see one extra whitespace on last line. is that what you are referring ?

Comment: running this in `node` produces `' # # # # \n# # # # \n # # # # \n# # # # \n # # # # \n# # # # \n # # # # \n# # # # \n'`. So the odd lines have nine characters, this can be troublesome if you want for instance draw a rectangle around it.

Comment: Ok, thanks Willem, I see your point. I will update the answer.